# What is an elegant way to clean this character vector?

Tags: r

```
a = c("\r\n            sql r sqldf \r\n        ", 
      "\r\n            r sample \r\n        ",
      "\r\n            r \r\n        ")
```

The result I want is

```
[1] "sql; r; sqldf"
[2] "r; sample"
[3] "r"
```

I have used multiple calls to `strsplit()` and an `sapply()` loop to obtain the result I want, but it takes me about 7 lines to code. I am wondering if there could be a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a combination of `trimws()` and `gsub()`.

```
gsub(" ", "; ", trimws(a))
# [1] "sql; r; sqldf" "r; sample"     "r"
```